# URL parameters not appearing in ASP.MVC when using variant of Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.beginform

I've got a view that defines a form as

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm( "Update", "CcisCase", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ccisEditForm" } ))
```

with a submit button:

In the `RegisterRoutes` method (in the `HttpApplication`-derived class in `global.asax.cs`), I've got:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute( "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}" );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CcisCase",
            "CcisCase/{action}/{cmDatabaseId}/{caseId}",
            new { Controller = "CcisCase", Action = "CcisCaseEdit", caseId = "" } );
```

The url generated by MVC ends with "/Update" but there are no parameters. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
 Bob

Answer (score 2):

What parameters are you expecting to see?  A post does not append parameters to the querystring, a FormMethod.Get would.  And, that overload with the id is the collection of HTML attributes to render for the  tag (which I'm assuming you knew, but just in case).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Your route contains a parameter {caseId} but your BeginForm only defines an id value.

```
new {id = "cssEditForm"}
```

You need something like this to include the caseId value

```
using (Html.BeginForm( "Update", "CcisCase", FormMethod.Post, new { caseId = 1, id = "ccisEditForm" }
```

If your action isn't using the id="ccisEditForm" value then you can remove that for less code clutter.

Comment: Thanks. I just posted my fix, and had to use both the strongly-typed RouteValueDictionary and Dictionary parameters (see my answer later).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was. I had to pass the existing route data as follows:

```
        using (Html.BeginForm( "Update", "CcisCase", ViewContext.RouteData.Values, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "ccisEditForm" } } ))
```